# How to create splash screen functionality by using programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, splash-screen

I am developing a universal application (iPhone, iPad). And I want to know how to create Splash screen by using objective-c, without using storyboards and Xib's.

Is this possible and how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, the launch screen is present while you app is being loaded. When you app is being loaded no code can be executed.

If you want on file use the new launch screen nib.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html

Comment: Here they mentioned Storyboards and xib's is work only in iOS8 or later only

Comment: Yes, sorry was confused with the iOS 6 and image assets. You will just need to provide both or stick with the image asset one.

Comment: but according to the user my splash screen image is change for that image asset is not work for me.